# How to assign value if not increment? laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-session

I want to assign a value if not exist else increment the value. Below is the one line code that I'm trying to achieve.

```
session()->put(['validation_count' => session('validation_count')++ ?? 1]);
```

But I end up this error below.

> Can't use function return value in write context

Someone knows the perfect one line solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$validationCount = session('validation_count');
session()->put(['validation_count' =>  ($validationCount ? $validationCount++ : 1]);
```

**Update for comment:**

I recommend with variable usage but if you want to one line:

```
session ()->put ( ['validation_count' => ( session ( 'validation_count' ) ? session ( 'validation_count' ) + 1 : 1 )] );
session ()->save ();
```

Comment: updated answer returns error **Can't use function return value in write context**

Comment: Please don't update or delete comment for other people. I updated again. Sorry my syntax mistake

Comment: Ok just add last line in my answer.

Comment: still stays in value 1

Comment: May be you have another mistake. Where are you using this? In controller?

Answer (score 0):

In one line, you can do like so:

`session()->put(['validation_count' =>  (session('validation_count') ? session('validation_count') + 1 : 1)]);`

Comment: I just edited it, there was a parentheses missing. It works for me. Try writing it twice and `var_dump(session('validation_count'))`, it should print 2.

Comment: still always stays in value 1. please try your solution first before answering.

Comment: I did try it, works for me. I wrote it twice and `dd` it and it shows 2. You might be doing something wrong.

Comment: nope I `session()->all()` but the value still stays in 1